# How to make multiple includes more efficient with EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a query with many multi level includes:

```cs
var itemsToday = DatabaseContext.Items
                .Where(f => f.StartTime > DateTime.Today && f.StartTime < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType1)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType2)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType3)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType4)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType5)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType6)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType7)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType8)
                .Include(x => x.LocalStats).ThenInclude(x=>x.StatType9)
                .Include(x => x.LocalDetails)
...
                .OrderBy(f=>f.SomeOrderingCriterion);
```

There are more includes than this. Of course, this causes EF Core 3.0 to generate *many* joins in the SQL query, which means it takes forever to execute (25+ seconds to retrieve 200 records).

I have tried using the format `.Include(x => x.LocalStats.StatType1)` instead of Include and ThenInclude, but the results are the same.

Is there any way of making this more efficient? The docs suggest that:

> LINQ queries with an exceedingly high number of `Include` operators may need to be broken down into multiple separate LINQ queries in order to avoid the cartesian explosion problem.

But I don't see any explanation on how to actually accomplish this.

Comment: @Silvermind I'm not sure if I understood what you said completely, but I *do* need all the data I am including. There are things which I am not including because I don't need them at this point. Unfortunately the objects are large and complex.

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/smitpatel/d4cb3619e5b33e8d9ea24d3f2a88333a) is their vision, according to [Breaking Changes - Eager loading of related entities now happens in a single query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#eager-loading-single-query)

Comment: @thedarkspoon I guess it generates Left Joins? With too many left joins the query can not be properly optimized and that's why you're getting a poor performance experience.

Comment: @thedarkspoon you got anything with this? I am also wondering what could be an alternative, since previous versions does actually consolidate these kinds of JOINs.

Comment: @Siege21x See my answer I just posted :)

Comment: @thedarkspoon thanks for that! But kind of a bit too tardy to make my own JOINs nowawayds. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up writing the SQL manually, I couldn't find a way of making the generated SQL efficient enough. Also consider looking at optimising the DB, for example adding clustered indexes. This cut down DB time by a significant portion.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider lazy loading this query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data